# Single URL for all the navigations in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a requirement of having the same URL throughout the application navigations. Like below
http://www.[Site Name]:com. (Here User should not have the idea of chaning the URL from one page to another page)

I am using ASP.NET MVC3 with latest Razor View Engine, 
Can some body give suggestions on this?

Advanced Thanks,
Satish Kotha

Comment: It depends on the complexity of your project, but you may want to look into using jquery to load partial views into the main content area of your site.

Answer (score 0):

This may make it very difficult for users to access your site - they won't be able to bookmark a specific page, for example.

It sounds like you want a single-page-app (e.g. like Google Mail or Reader). In this case, you have one page and make heavy use of AJAX. You can query the server via javascript, and send back Partial Views, or raw data in JSON format which can be rendered on the client, possibly via some kind of templating engine.

Comment: We have the same, not to give a chance to bookmark our application pages. Can you give some idea how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

As Graham Clark has already mentioned, this functionality will most likely be frustrating for the user; however, achieving it depends on the complexity of your project. You may want to look into using jquery to load partial views into the main content area of your site.

When you click on your navigation you can use jquery's [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to replace the main content on the page. [Jquery-load-with-mvc-2-partialviews](http://blog.devlpr.net/2011/01/03/jquery-load-with-mvc-2-partialviews/) is an interesting blog post that may give you more insight into what you would want to do. Your code to load content could look something like this:

```
$("#mainContent").load("/Controller/Action",
   {parameter}, function () {
   // perform javascript actions on load complete
});
```